# Is it possible to convert salesforce license into chatter plus license (downgrade) in salesforce?

Tags: chatter, licenses

Is it possible to convert salesforce license into chatter plus license (downgrade) in salesforce?

I already known the Chatter only license to salesforce license is possible (upgrade).

> but I have the doubt in downgrade salesforce license  >> chatter only license?

Could you please any one help to get out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't downgrade a license. You would have to create a new user record, and optionally disable the original user license if you need to free it up for someone else.

Comment: Just for getting Knowledge.. For converting the chatter plus license into salesforce license is not the best practice? or SFDC can't allow to change the chatter plus license into salesforce license?

Comment: @MohanRaj You can change from chatter licenses to CRM licenses, but not the other way around.